# How To Make This For Loop Faster

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, encryption

I have the problem that this for loop takes so much time to complete.
I want a faster way to complete it.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i,
                     base64BlockSize));
    arrayList.AddRange(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true));
}
```

The `iterations` variable sometimes is larger than 100,000 and that takes like for ever.

Comment: RSA (asymmetric) encryption is much slower than symmetric (ex: AES) encryption, use symmetric to encrypt data, asymmetric to encrypt symmetric keys.

Comment: yes this is the RSA asymmetric algorithim if you know it ,it cant take large data so i'm divide the string to make it right

Comment: i'm working on a homework so i'm forced to use it

Comment: That is not the way to do it. Instead create a symmetric key, encrypt the data with a symmetric algorithm and if need be encrypt the symmetric key with RSA. That is essentially how https works. If you do not have a need for asymmetric encryption (public/private key pairs) don't use it.

Comment: Decryption should be slow,  otherwise it is vulnerable to time based attacks.

Comment: i know what are you talking about and i work on that too and it works fine and it's fast but this takes time like hell to complete

Comment: Get a better instructor, instructors should not teach methods that are not used in practice.

Comment: lol Asymmetric algorithm works fine with text file but with video or even image file it take so much time to work

Comment: @RonBeyer No, there is no reason for decryption to be slow given the current key sizes. You may be confusing key derivation such as PBKDF2 and bcrypt which should be slow.

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi Why did you ask this question if you're unwilling to take the advice? There's really no other way to speed up the for loop without changing the logic inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider running the decryption process in a parallel loop. Your input strings have to be prepared first in a regular loop, but that's a quick process. Then you run the decryption in `Parallel.For`:

```
var inputs = new List<string>();
var result = new string[(inputString.Length / 64) - 1];

// Create inputs from the input string.
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{
    inputs.Add(inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));
}

Parallel.For(0, iterations, i =>
{
    var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputs[i]);
    result[i] = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true);
});
```

I assumed the result returned is a string but if that's not the case then you have to adjust the type for the concurrent bag collection.

Comment: That code sure appears to break if the results don't come back in sequence.  Aren't ConcurrentBags unordered as well?

Comment: Fair point. It is unordered. Probably a version relying on a ConcurrentDictionary and applying integers as keys is a better option. Let me update my code.

Comment: A regular string array would work as well I think without all the concurrency overhead. `var result = new string[iterations];`

Comment: Tested and it worked so I've updated that with a string array. Thanks for your suggestion.